# Python script that makes ngrams

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

This is a Python script that generates ngrams using a set of rules of what letters can follow a letter stored in a dictionary.

The output is then preliminarily processed using another script, then it will be filtered further using an api of sorts by number of words containing the ngrams, the result will be used in pseudoword generation.

This is the generation part:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
import sys

LETTERS = set(ascii_lowercase)
VOWELS = set('aeiouy')
CONSONANTS = LETTERS - VOWELS

BASETAILS = {
    'a': CONSONANTS,
    'b': 'bjlr',
    'c': 'chjklr',
    'd': 'dgjw',
    'e': CONSONANTS,
    'f': 'fjlr',
    'g': 'ghjlrw',
    'h': '',
    'i': CONSONANTS,
    'j': '',
    'k': 'hklrvw',
    'l': 'l',
    'm': 'cm',
    'n': 'gn',
    'o': CONSONANTS,
    'p': 'fhlprst',
    'q': '',
    'r': 'hrw',
    's': 'chjklmnpqstw',
    't': 'hjrstw',
    'u': CONSONANTS,
    'v': 'lv',
    'w': 'hr',
    'x': 'h',
    'y': 'sv',
    'z': 'hlvw'
}

tails = dict()

for i in ascii_lowercase:
    v = BASETAILS[i]
    if type(v) == set:
        v = ''.join(sorted(v))
    tails.update({i: ''.join(sorted('aeiou' + v))})

def makechain(invar, target, depth=0):
    depth += 1
    if type(invar) == str:
        invar = set(invar)
    chain = invar.copy()
    if depth == target:
        return sorted(chain)
    else:
        for i in invar:
            for j in tails[i[-1]]:
                chain.add(i + j)
        return makechain(chain, target, depth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    invar = sys.argv[1]
    target = int(sys.argv[2])
    if invar in globals():
        invar = eval(invar)
    print(*makechain(invar, target), sep='\n')
```

I want to ask about the `makechain` function, I used `set`s because somehow the results can contain duplicates if I used `list`s, though the result can be cast to `set`, I used a nested `for` loop and a recursive function to simulate a variable number of for loops.

For example, `makechain(LETTERS, 4)` is equivalent to:

```py
chain = set()
for a in LETTERS:
    chain.add(a)
for a in LETTERS:
    for b in tails[a]:
        chain.add(a + b)
for a in LETTERS:
    for b in tails[a]:
        for c in tails[b]:
            chain.add(a + b + c)
for a in LETTERS:
    for b in tails[a]:
        for c in tails[b]:
            for d in tails[c]:
                chain.add(a + b + c + d)
```

Obviously `makechain(LETTERS, 4)` is much better than the nested for loop approach, it is much more flexible.

I want to know, is there anyway I can use a function from `itertools` instead of the nested `for` loop to generate the same results more efficiently?

I am thinking about `itertools.product` and `itertools.combinations` but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Type checking

Don't do `if type(var) == cls`, instead do:

```py
if isinstance(var, cls):
```

### `tails`

This can be built via a dictionary comprehension rather than iterating over `ascii_lowercase` and looking up against `BASETAILS` every time:

```py
tails = {
    i: ''.join(sorted(VOWELS + v))
    for i, v in BASETAILS.items()
}
```

### `makechain` vs loops

Your n-depth loops are really just a cartesian product of `LETTERS` and `tails`, which can be accomplished, as you suspected, with `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product

def build_chain(letters, tails, depth, chain=None):
    chain = chain if chain is not None else set()

    if not depth - 1:
        return chain.union(letters)

    num_tails = [letters]

    for _ in range(depth - 1):
        chain.update(
            ''.join(c) for c in product(*num_tails)
        )
        
        last = its[-1]
        num_tails.append(''.join(map(tails.get, last)))

    return chain
```

Where this assumes that every entry in `tails.values()` is a string and `letters` is also a string

Answer (score 4):

> Any help will be appreciated

A few suggestions on something that I noticed:

- In the function `makechain` the `else` after the `return` is not necessary.
- Typo in: `VOWELS = set('aeiouy')`, there is an extra `y`.
- This part:

  ```
  LETTERS = set(ascii_lowercase)
  VOWELS = set('aeiou')
  CONSONANTS = LETTERS - VOWELS

  BASETAILS = {
      'a': CONSONANTS,
      'b': 'bjlr',
      'c': 'chjklr',
      'd': 'dgjw',
       ....
      }

  tails = dict()

  for i in ascii_lowercase:
      v = BASETAILS[i]
      if type(v) == set:
          v = ''.join(sorted(v))
      tails.update({i: ''.join(sorted('aeiou' + v))})
  ```

  seems to do the following:

  1. Create a dictionary with mixed value's type (strings and sets)
  2. Convert all values to string
  3. Sort dictionary's values

  It could be simplified to:

  1. Create a dictionary where all values are strings
  2. Sort dictionary's values

  Additionally, having `VOWELS` as a set and `CONSONANTS` as a string is a bit confusing. Would be better to use only one type.

  Code with suggestions above:

  ```
  LETTERS = ascii_lowercase
  VOWELS = 'aeiou'
  CONSONANTS = ''.join(set(LETTERS) - set(VOWELS))

  BASETAILS = {
      'a': CONSONANTS,
      'b': 'bjlr',
      'c': 'chjklr',
      'd': 'dgjw',
      ....
      }

  tails = dict()

  for i in ascii_lowercase:
      v = BASETAILS[i]
      tails.update({i: ''.join(sorted(VOWELS + v))})
  ```

  In this way, you also avoid sorting twice.

Comment: Correction, y in `'aeiouy'` is not a typo, I know y isn't a full vowel, but it is a half-vowel, it acts as a vowel in many English words, such as many, cyber, psycho, dry... So it can be used as a vowel for pseudoword generation.